# How do you say "I walked in the park" in German?

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-german

How do Germans say "I walked in the park/in the woods yesterday"?

My dictionary translates *to walk* as *(spazieren) gehen* and *laufen*. I thought *to walk*, as in *I walked in the woods*, didn't indicate a change of location or need a destination. So its perfect tense would need *haben* as the auxiliary verb. (When *gehen/laufen* means *to go/run somewhere* it has to be *sein + past participle*, of course.)

But all the examples in the dictionary are written with *sein* like *Wir sind im Urlaub viel gelaufen.* and it says both *gehen* and *laufen* take *sein* to form the perfect in any case.

I don't know the reason why I have to put *sein* in that case, even when there's no movement from somewhere to somewhere. Can anybody make me understand?

Comment: there's no question here, the perfect tense of *laufen* and *gehen* is formed with sein, full stop. Ich bin (gestern) im Park spazieren gegangen.

Comment: Well, walking certainly implies a movement, even though you may return to the starting point. There are corner cases (e.g. treadmills), but grammatically, _gehen_ and _laufen_ are always verbs of movements.

Comment: I walked in the dark. - Andere Frage: Wieso mit Hilfsverb, und nicht einfach `Ich spazierte im Park`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your title question, as the comments above state, it would be,

> Ich bin im Park spazieren gegangen.

(or possibly "Ich bin im Park gelaufen", since you brought up that verb, though that wouldn't necessarily indicate a stroll in the park).

If you want to use something other than *sein*, then you would have to switch to something like *einen Spaziergang machen* and use *haben* to form the perfect of *machen*, but that merely uses a different verb altogether.

Also, as stated in the comments above, verbs like *gehen* and *laufen* are always verbs of movement and take *sein* to form the perfect tense. *Walking* by definition indicates some sort of directional movement. Even walking in place merely transfers the movement into perhaps a vertical plane for up and down movements. But you can't technically be walking and be stationary at the same time.

Comment: Just fixed "spazierengegangen" -> "spazieren gegangen".

Answer (score 4):

When you walk you move. With every single step you leave the position that you had before you made this step. This per definition is movement. There is no need to have a target to where you want to move to. As long as there is any path that is not a single point, it is a movement.

And because all verbs of movement use *»sein«* as auxiliary verb, also *»spazieren«* uses *»sein«*.

Note, that *"I walked in the park"* can mean two different things:

1. You are already in park, and you walk inside the park without leaving it:

   > Ich spazierte im Park. *(tense: Präteritum)*
   >   Ich bin im Park spaziert. *(tense: Perfekt)*
2. You are outside the park and are going to enter it:

   > Ich spazierte in den Park.
   >   Ich bin in den Park spaziert.

But more often you don't use the verb *spazieren* as main verb. You just put its infinitive aside the verb *gehen* which of course is a verb of movement too and therefor needs a form of *sein* when used in *Perfekt*:

> Ich ging im Park spazieren.
>   Ich bin im Park spazieren gegangen.

But you can use *spazieren + gehen* only to express, that you are already in the park. You can't use this combination to tell that you entered the park.

Answer (score 3):

"I walked in the park" is past tense. The correct translation therefore has to be "Ich spazierte im Park." or "Ich ging im Park spazieren."

Comment: Or "Ich bin im Park spazieren gegangen" but not "Ich habe im Park spazieren genangen" what OP is assuming.

Comment: Da der Gebrauch der Zeiten im Deutschen und im Englischen verschieden ist, muss die *past tense* nicht mit dem Imperfekt übersetzt werden, das Perfekt ist auch möglich.

Comment: Die Frage war: *Warum wird als Hilfsverb nicht »haben« verwendet, sondern »sein«* Du gehst darauf nicht einmal am Rande ein. Außerdem können die englischen Zeiten nicht 1:1 auf die deutschen abgebildet werden. Selbst innerhalb des deutschen Sprachraums gibt es hier Unterschiede. In Österreich käme kein Mensch auf die Idee zu sagen »Ich ging spazieren«, weil das Perfekt hier kaum verwendet wird. Österreicher sagen »Ich bin spazieren gegangen«, egal ob sie sich noch auf der letzten Etappe ihres Spaziergangs befinden, oder ob sie von einem Spaziergang reden, der vor 30 Jahren stattgefunden hat.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: nur so als Tip: wenn du alte oder sehr alte Fragen oder Antworten bearbeitest lohnt zuvor ein Blick in das [User-Profil](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/3264/volker-ackermann?tab=profile). Volker war insgesamt nur an 3 Tagen hier, zuletzt (*last seen*) **vor 5 Jahren** und auch der Fragesteller ist leider seit 2 Jahren nicht mehr hier gewesen. Deine Antwort, Dein Vote und Dein Kommentar verpuffen also wahrscheinlich im schwarzen Loch des Internet. Die Frage wurde nur hochgespült, weil irgendein Witzbold eine Nonesense-Antwort gepostet hat.

Comment: @Takkat Aber was soll aus dem Tipp folgen? Dass alte Fragen – ab wann gelten sie überhaupt als alt? – nicht mehr beantwortet oder kommentiert werden sollen? Dem würde ich dann widersprechen, denn Antworten sollen nicht nur den OP zufriedenstellen, sondern auch Interessierte, die vielleicht Jahre später eine ähnliche Frage haben; und für die können auch spät getätigte Antworten oder Kommentare hilfreich sein.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: es geht mir hier hauptsächlich **um den Kommentar** und das Downvote , das jemand hier mit -1 für sich selber abgesetzt hat . Beide sollen wohl einer Person irgendetwas sagen, die aber vermutlich nie wieder kommen wird. Kann man natürlich schon machen, wenn man viel Zeit übrig hat, aber es vermüllt eigentlich nur die Seite.

Comment: @Takkat: Was habe ich deiner Meinung nach bearbeitet? Ich habe eine Frage, die  ganz weit oben in der Liste der Top Questions stand beantwortet, und habe davor die anderen Antworten gelesen, und dabei eine gefunden, die durch die unsinnig hohe Punktezahl den Eindruck gemacht hat, gut zu sein, was sie aber nicht ist. Daher habe ich diese schlechte Antwort abgewertet und habe das mit einem Kommentar begründet, damit nicht auch andere wissen, was schlecht an dieser Antwort ist. Ich weiß nicht, was an meiner Vorgehensweise zu bemängeln sein soll.

Comment: Das, was die Seite vermüllt sind schlechte Antworten (insbesondere wenn sie viele Punkte bekommen haben) und so manche Diskussionen, die von Moderatoren angestoßen wurden, die offenbar viel Zeit übrig haben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: war bloß ein gut gemeinter Rat, wie man mit uralten und verlassenen Fragen sinnvoller umgehen kann.